# Bulk .htaccess Redirect - query string to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm going to need to redirect about 700 urls that look like this...

mydomain.com/index.php?id=3&d_id=8297

..to the new appropriate page in a wordpress site.

Assuming that I change the new wordpress slug to something that includes the 4 digit number,
is there a way to do this in .htaccess using a formula (so I don't have to do it for each one separately)?

Thanks

Comment: So what should the new URL look like for above URI in question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule as your **very first rule** in WP .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?id=[0-9]+&d_id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem...  the URLS that I need to change were in a Zeemap.  Zeemaps allows you to export and import data through a spread sheet.  I can make the new URLS mydomainname.com/1234 and use find and replace on the first portion of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Me again.  I ended up using the .htaccess to redirect the pages to the WordPress search results for the page number.

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?id=[0-9]+&d_id=([0-9]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /?s=%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Thanks for your help!